# Solution of an equation with a taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

Show that $$x=ne^{-x}$$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n\ge1$ has one solution $x_n$ such that: $$x_n = \log(n)-\log(\log(n)) + o(\log(n))= \log(n)-\log(\log(n)) + o(1)$$

**My try:**
Let be $$f(x)=x-ne^{-x}$$
$f(0)=-n<0$ and $f'(x)=1+ne^{-x} >0$ for all $x$, so $f(x)$ is increasing and there will be $x_n \in (0, +∞)$ for which $f(x_n)=0$.
Which is the next step? Show that $x_n+\log(x_n)=\log(n)$…?

Comment: Actually, $f'(x) > 0$ doesn't necessarily show that there is a root on $(0,\infty)$ (but $f'(x) > 1$ $\forall x$ with $f(0) < 0$ does).  Use the intermediate value theorem, and the properties of $f$:  $f(0) = -n < 0$, $f(n) = n(1-e^{-n}) > 0$, and $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.  This proves that there is a root $x_n \in (0,n)$.  Furthermore, the root is unique (this actually follows from the fact that $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$).

Comment: Yes true, i forgot to say that $f(x)$ is not bounded above, that is easier.

Comment: The details are a bit fuzzy yet, but maybe this can be modified a bit to work?

$f(x_n) = 0$, so setting $x_n = y$, $y e^{y} = n$, or taking the log of both sides, we get $\log(n) = \log(y) + y$.  And it seems that it wouldn't be too difficult to arrive at $y = \log(n) - \log(\log(n)) + \text{error}$, but that's as far as I got.  We still would need to show that $\text{error} = o(\log(n))$.

Comment: and also that $\text{error} = o(1)$ (which may prove slightly less difficult).

Comment: using the last relation above we have $\log(x_n)=\log(\log(n))-\log(\log(x_n))$ and substituting: $x_n = \log(n)-\log(\log(n))+\log(\log(x_n))$. Any ideas now to show that $\log(\log(x_n)) = o(\log(n))?$